# Linking Azure virtual machine to Trend Micro CloudOne workload security

Tags: azure

I am trying to connect my Azure VM (inside of a private intranet with no internet connection) to Trend Micro CloudOne Workload security for management without allowing internet access other than a proxy? or can Azure private link service or private endpoint do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

To establish a connection between your VMs (which they should be on a virtual network too) and an on-premises network, you need a VPN gateway and an approved VPN device on-prem in order to set up what we call a site-to-site VPN or a Point-To-Site VPN
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal#:~:text=A%20Site%2Dto%2DSite%20VPN%20gateway%20connection%20is%20used%20to,IP%20address%20assigned%20to%20it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal#:%7E:text=A%20Site%2Dto%2DSite%20VPN%20gateway%20connection%20is%20used%20to,IP%20address%20assigned%20to%20it).